# Pandas time index DataFrame group by time difference

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a time indexed DataFrame looking like this:

```
>>> df
                             A
index
2019-07-13 13:01:27.100      1
2019-07-13 13:01:27.674      2
2019-07-13 13:01:28.233      4
2019-07-13 13:01:28.534      1
2019-07-13 13:01:29.005      6
2019-07-13 13:01:29.732      7
2019-07-13 13:01:35.353      1
2019-07-13 13:01:35.547      9
2019-07-13 13:01:36.125      2
2019-07-13 13:01:36.626      3
2019-07-13 13:01:37.046      4
2019-07-13 13:01:37.734      7
2019-07-13 13:01:43.156      4
2019-07-13 13:01:43.523      6
2019-07-13 13:01:44.291      2
2019-07-13 13:01:44.784      5
2019-07-13 13:01:50.046      3
2019-07-13 13:01:50.563      8
2019-07-13 13:01:51.912      5
```

I would like to have groups where the included datapoints are not more then 5 seconds apart. For example the first group would be from 13:01:27.100 until 13:01:29.732, the second from 13:01:35.353 until 13:01:37.734 and so on...

Is there a fast way to do that for a large dataset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually done with help of `diff` and `groupby`:

```
df['group'] = df.index.to_series().diff().gt('5sec').cumsum()
```

Output:

```
                         A  group
index                            
2019-07-13 13:01:27.100  1      0
2019-07-13 13:01:27.674  2      0
2019-07-13 13:01:28.233  4      0
2019-07-13 13:01:28.534  1      0
2019-07-13 13:01:29.005  6      0
2019-07-13 13:01:29.732  7      0
2019-07-13 13:01:35.353  1      1
2019-07-13 13:01:35.547  9      1
2019-07-13 13:01:36.125  2      1
2019-07-13 13:01:36.626  3      1
2019-07-13 13:01:37.046  4      1
2019-07-13 13:01:37.734  7      1
2019-07-13 13:01:43.156  4      2
2019-07-13 13:01:43.523  6      2
2019-07-13 13:01:44.291  2      2
2019-07-13 13:01:44.784  5      2
2019-07-13 13:01:50.046  3      3
2019-07-13 13:01:50.563  8      3
2019-07-13 13:01:51.912  5      3
```

Comment: This has always seemed the fastest according to my experience

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use **Grouper** class, look at **freq** parameter.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html